# Is this true or false? I've not seen a standardisation of this form (n(Un - U)/sigma^2) before? Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, discrete-mathematics, statistical-inference

[Please see the link for the question, have not seen a standardisation of that form before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubCmO.png)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: It looks as if the numerators should be squared and there are other issues too such as the disappearing $10$